# Use same usestate hook for multiple icons

Tags: reactjs

I have a two buttons in my react project (material ui icons) which are lowerarrow(both) and i made a use state and function to change upper arrow to lower arrow when it is clicked but i dont know how to use the same state for my another icon too, maybe using some id or something  i dont know , right now i put {iconstate} in both the icons so both the icons are changing together i am trying to figure out how to change them individually without making new state and function here is my code :-
JSX:-

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import Weather_leftpanecss from './Weather_leftpane.module.css'
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowUp';

export default function Weather_leftpane() {

  const [iconstate, seticonstate] = useState(<KeyboardArrowDownIcon/>)
  const [valuestate, setvaluestate] = useState(true)


  const togglearrow = ()=>{
    if(valuestate==true){
      seticonstate(<KeyboardArrowUpIcon/>)
      setvaluestate(false)

    }
    else{
      seticonstate(<KeyboardArrowDownIcon/>)
      setvaluestate(true)
    }
  }

  return <div>
      <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.main}>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_1}>Weather</div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_2}>
          <input type="text" placeholder='Search for city..' />
        </div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3}>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3_content} id="item_3_1">
            Cities
          </div>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3_content} id="item_3_2" onClick={togglearrow} >
            {iconstate}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4}>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4_content} id="item_4_1">
            Settings
          </div>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4_content} id="item_4_2" onClick={togglearrow}>
            {iconstate}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>;
}
```

css:-

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

(not the real css ,just added it because i have included it everywhere in my code with module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you need to save the selected Id in the state.

```
import React , {useState} from 'react';
import Weather_leftpanecss from './Weather_leftpane.module.css'
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown';
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowUp';

export default function Weather_leftpane() {

  const [valuestate, setvaluestate] = useState(true)
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);


  const togglearrow = (val)=>{        
    if(valuestate==true){
      setvaluestate(false)
    }else{
      setvaluestate(true)
    }
    setId(val);
  }

  return <div>
      <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.main}>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_1}>Weather</div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_2}>
          <input type="text" placeholder='Search for city..' />
        </div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3}>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3_content} id="item_3_1">
            Cities
          </div>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3_content} id="item_3_2" onClick={() => togglearrow('item_3_2')} >
            {valuestate && id == 'item_3_2' ? KeyboardArrowUpIcon : KeyboardArrowDownIcon }
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4}>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4_content} id="item_4_1">
            Settings
          </div>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4_content} id="item_4_2" onClick={() => togglearrow('item_4_1')}>
          {valuestate && id == 'item_4_1' ? KeyboardArrowUpIcon : KeyboardArrowDownIcon }
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

  </div>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying i tried to run your code and there was an error in the console which is not letting the component to render :- Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @Samyakjain ohh sorry about that, actually I forgot to use the icon as html tags in the ternary condition at first, but then I updated the answer and fixed it, not sure why It did not display in the post, you can check the edited version of the answer.

Comment: Ohh yeah its working perfectly fine now

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use one state to achieve that, saving in one state the status of both buttons, which one is clicked or not and render the icon based on that status.

the **toggleArrow** function gets the itemId and uses it to set the updated value of the button. We use !prevState[itemId] since if it is false it will become true and vise versa.

I took the liberty of giving the state a more informative name than a generic name.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Weather_leftpanecss from "./Weather_leftpane.module.css";
import KeyboardArrowDownIcon from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowDown";
import KeyboardArrowUpIcon from "@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowUp";

export default function Weather_leftpane() {
  const [clickedButtons, setClickedButtons] = useState({
    item_3_2: false,
    item_4_2: false
  });

  const toggleArrow = (itemId) => {
    setClickedButtons((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [itemId]: !prevState[itemId]
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.main}>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_1}>Weather</div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_2}>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search for city.." />
        </div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3}>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3_content} id="item_3_1">
            Cities
          </div>
          <div
            className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_3_content}
            id="item_3_2"
            onClick={() => toggleArrow("item_3_2")}
          >
            {clickedButtons["item_3_2"] ? (
              <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4}>
          <div className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4_content} id="item_4_1">
            Settings
          </div>
          <div
            className={Weather_leftpanecss.item_4_content}
            id="item_4_2"
            onClick={() => toggleArrow("item_4_2")}
          >
            {clickedButtons["item_4_2"] ? (
              <KeyboardArrowUpIcon />
            ) : (
              <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: @Samyakjain Glad I could help, I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as the solution for your problem/upvote so I could further help people.

Comment: Ohh i already did it

Comment: @Samyakjain Sorry, my mistake, I guess I didn't refresh. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your help , also if you could , can you help on my other react question? Its about connecting react js with node js

Comment: @Samyakjain You should provide some code there so people can understand the issue, I can try but if I'm not sure of the solution I cannot submit an answer.

Comment: I dont know what code should i add there to make people understand? All i want to do is show my react app when someone logs in using express

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241297/discussion-between-b-nadler-and-samyak-jain).